# Connect 4 Java Project - Issues with determining when a column is full

Tags: java, arrays, project

```
if (count % 2 == 0) {

    int columnMove;
    System.out.print("Player one, please enter a move or q to quit: ");
    columnMove = scan.nextInt() - 1;

    if (columnMove <= columns - 1 && columnMove >= 0) {
        turns = true;
        game.playerOnePrompt(board, columns, rows, columnMove);
        ++count;
        if (board[0][columnMove] != "_") {
            System.out.println("This column is full");
            count = 0;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid move");
        count = 0;
    }

} else {

    int columnMove;
    System.out.print("Player two, please enter a move: ");
    columnMove = scan.nextInt() - 1;

    if (columnMove <= columns - 1 && columnMove >= 0) {
        turns = true;
        game.playerTwoPrompt(board, columns, rows, columnMove);
        count++;
        if (board[0][columnMove] != "_") {
            System.out.println("This column is full");
            count = 1;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid move");
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

Hello! Above is my code to determine whether an array (columns) is full, if it is full, the user should be prompt to make another move.

However I am having an issue where the program sees that it is full, prompts the user, and after the user makes a valid move, the program does not shift the players (from player 1 - 2 - 1 - 2 etc).

Any advice?

Comment: this is not the full code... in order to help you, help us by giving the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if (board[0][columnMove] != "_")
    {
        System.out.println("This column is full");
        count = 0;
    }
```

You are always setting count to zero, whenever the move is valid.

Comment: If i dont reset the count,
Then if the user inputs a move in a full column, the user's "turn" will get registered, and move on to player 2.
Is there a better way to reset the count?

Comment: "and after the user makes a valid move, the program does not shift the players". Change assignment to equal to 1 for first if branch, and to equal zero for second.

Answer (score 0):

```
    maximumNumberOfMoves = boardWidth * boardHeight;
    if (count == maximumNumberOfMoves) {
        // end game
    } else if (count % 2 == 0) {
        int columnMove;
        System.out.print("Player one, please enter a move or q to quit: ");
        columnMove = scan.nextInt() - 1;
        if (columnMove <= columns - 1 && columnMove >= 0) {
            turns = true;
            game.playerOnePrompt(board, columns, rows, columnMove);
            ++count;
            if (board[0][columnMove] != "_") {
                System.out.println("This column is full");
                --count; // We must decrement count if we want the same
                            // player to move again
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid move");
            // count = 0; //Remove this, count was not modified
        }

    } else {
        int columnMove;
        System.out.print("Player two, please enter a move: ");
        columnMove = scan.nextInt() - 1;
        if (columnMove <= columns - 1 && columnMove >= 0) {
            turns = true;
            game.playerTwoPrompt(board, columns, rows, columnMove);
            count++;
            if (board[0][columnMove] != "_") {
                System.out.println("This column is full");
                --count; // We must decrement count if we want the same
                            // player to move again
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid move");
            // count = 1; //Again, remove this since count is not modified
        }
    }
```

Note the commented lines for fixed code

This answer assumes count represents the number of moves made so far and begins at 0.

Comment: It is still repeating once i get to the last row of the game.
Is there a better way for me to show you my problem?
The program is pretty long and in 2 segments.

Comment: Do you mean when all slots are full (game ends in tie)? See edited answer

Comment: When every row, except for the last row is filled. 
so it'll look like 
_ _ _ _ _
X O X O X
X O X O X

once the player starts to play on the last row
Whoever places the first piece down, is the one that is repeated.
X X X X X
X O X O X 
X O X O X 

or 

O O O O O 
X O X O X
X O X O X

Comment: Wow, that did not come out the way i expected it to.
The game does end in a tie, the program is able to do that.
I just cant get the last row to function correctly.
Everything else in the game runs smooth.

Comment: I figured it out Thanks for the pointers!
I just added more restrictions to the if statement.
if (board[0][columnMove]!= "X" && board[0][columnMove]!="_")

Comment: If my answer is close to correct you can edit it and then approve it so that others may easily solve similar problems in the future